# Change CSS background color when DIV in viewport

Tags: javascript, html, css, background-color

is it possible to change the background color of my website when a specific div is in the viewport? And would it be possible to change the background color again (i.e. for the 2nd time) if another DIV is in the viewport?

So something like this:

***BLUE
BLUE
BLUE*
...
DIV1 (in the viewport = background color RED)
*RED
RED
RED*
...
DIV2 (in the viewport = background color BLUE)
*BLUE
BLUE
BLUE***

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand it right, If you are talking about just changing background-color when you reach a particular viewport on scroll or change the background-color on viewport on media query yes that is possible. what have you tried so far? providing your code is better for this community so everyone can see your problem or your goal.

Comment: @Crystal Yes, that would be a possibility. If I changed the background color from a certain height, it wouldn't really be responsive, because if the grid changes, for example, the height at which the background color changes is not correct. Unfortunately I don't have the right code yet, I currently have no idea how to implement the whole thing. The aim would be to change the background color from a DIV, because the DIV is always in the same position on both the PC and the smartphone, from which the color should change. :)

Comment: @Andreas Check my answer below

Comment: Use IntersectionObserver to tell you when a particlar element is in the viewport.

Comment: @Andreas check out that sample of css below that will help you navigate on the viewport that you want to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Explanation**

"When the user scrolls to the **TOP** of the blue div, the background color of the body changes to red."

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  if (scroll >= $('#blue').offset().top) {
    $('body').css('background-color', 'red');
  }
  if (scroll >= $('#black').offset().top) {
    $('body').css('background-color', 'blue');
  }
  if (scroll >= $('#black').last().offset().top) {
    $('body').css('background-color', 'green');
  }
});
```

```css
#blue {
  width: 400px;
  height: 800px;
  background: blue;
}

#black {
  width: 400px;
  height: 800px;
  background: black;
}

#red {
  width: 400px;
  height: 800px;
  background: red;
  margin-bottom: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="blue"></div>
<div id="black"></div>
<div id="red"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can always call that on the media query to change anything you want at particular height or color heres an example if i understand you right

```css
body {background-color:gray;}
.mygridboxes {
    display:grid;
}

.box {
    height:500px;
    width:500px;
    background-color:red;
    font-size:50px;
    text-align:center;
    margin:0 auto;
    border:10px solid white;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:1024px){

body {
    background-color:yellow;
}
.box {
     background-color:green;//change background
     height:350px; //resize height
     width:350px;} 
}


@media only screen and (max-width:768px){
body {
    background-color:yellow;
}
.box {
     background-color:green;//change background
     height:300px; //resize height
     width:300px;} 
}


@media only screen and (max-width:479px){

body {background-color:blue;}
.box {
    background-color:pink;//change background
    height:200px; //resize the height here
    width:200px;
}
}
```

```html
<body>
<h1>RESIZE ME</h1>
  <div class="mygridboxes">
   <div class="box">A</div>
   <div class="box">B</div>
   <div class="box">C</div>
   <div class="box">D</div> 
</div>
</body>
```